# GCC 11: How to tell CMake I don't want the default C++ GNU extensions?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, c++17

So, back in GCC 10.2 (which used C++14 as the default), I could use this to tell CMake I wanted `-std=gnu++17`:

```
target_compile_features(mytarget PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
set_target_properties(mytarget PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
)
```

...which I actually *didn't* want, so I used `CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF` to force `-std=c++17`:

```
target_compile_features(mytarget PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
set_target_properties(mytarget PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
    CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF  # -std=c++17 instead of gnu++17
)
```

Enter GCC 11.1. The default now is the 2017 version of the ISO C++ standard, so that the first snippet above doesn't generate *any* `-std` flag for GCC, which is compatible with GCC 11's man page:

> `c++17`: The 2017 ISO C++ standard plus amendments.
>
> `gnu++17`: GNU dialect of `-std=c++17`.  This is the default for C++ code.

The problem is that **the second CMake snippet above also doesn't generate any `-std` flag**. How do I do it now, is this a bug in CMake? How to I tell it I want an explicit `-std=c++17` flag?

Remark 1: I know I can just stick `-std=c++17` in `target_compile_options`, but I don't want to do that, do I?

Remark 2: Sanity check: if I change `cxx_std_17` to `cxx_std_20`, then `CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF` correctly switches from `-std=gnu++2a` to `-std=c++2a`.

Comment: What version of CMake are you using? Is it newer than GCC 11.1? The rule is that you should not use a version of CMake older than your compiler. If you are using a recent enough version, then yes this is a bug.

Comment: Also `CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` is redundant with the `cxx_std_NN` compiler feature AFAIK

Comment: Hmmm looks like CMake 3.20.2 is indeed older than GCC 11, thanks! (Though it's been announced for quite long that GCC 11 would bump the C++ default to C++17, and cmake isn't exactly unaware of that since it actively omits `-std=gnu++17` in the first case.)

Comment: Well, since you're on the _newest_ version, it might still be worth opening an issue so the problem disappears on the _next_ version.

Comment: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues

Comment: done: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22224

Comment: The following merge request should fix this and is scheduled for CMake 3.22 -- https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/6177

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this question is that it is a bug in CMake 3.21 (but technically not 3.20, which is older than the compiler in question) that will be fixed in 3.22, most likely by the following merge request: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/6177